# ROW_NUMBER query

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have a table:

```
Trip  Stop  Time 
-----------------
1     A     1:10
1     B     1:16
1     B     1:20
1     B     1:25
1     C     1:31
1     B     1:40
2     A     2:10
2     B     2:17
2     C     2:20
2     B     2:25
```

I want to add one more column to my query output:

```
Trip  Stop  Time Sequence
-------------------------
1     A     1:10   1
1     B     1:16   2 
1     B     1:20   2
1     B     1:25   2
1     C     1:31   3
1     B     1:40   4 
2     A     2:10   1
2     B     2:17   2
2     C     2:20   3
2     B     2:25   4
```

The hard part is B, if B is next to each other I want it to be the same sequence, if not then count as a new row.

I know

```
row_number over (partition by trip order by time)
row_number over (partition by trip, stop order by time)
```

None of them will meet the condition I want. Is there a way to query this?

Comment: Is this for `sql-server` ? Or what other RDBMS is this for? Please add a relevant tag!

Comment: Oracle SQL sorry I tried to add free tag but my level can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table test
(trip number
,stp  varchar2(1)
,tm   varchar2(10)
,seq  number);

insert into test values (1,     'A',     '1:10',   1);
insert into test values (1,     'B',     '1:16',   2); 
insert into test values (1,     'B',     '1:20',   2);
insert into test values (1 ,    'B',     '1:25',   2);
insert into test values (1 ,    'C',     '1:31',   3);
insert into test values (1,     'B',     '1:40',   4);
insert into test values (2,     'A',     '2:10',   1);
insert into test values (2,     'B',     '2:17',   2);
insert into test values (2,     'C',     '2:20',   3);
insert into test values (2,     'B',     '2:25',   4);

select t1.*
      ,sum(decode(t1.stp,t1.prev_stp,0,1)) over (partition by trip order by tm) new_seq
from  
     (select t.*
            ,lag(stp) over (order by t.tm) prev_stp
      from   test t
      order  by tm) t1
;

  TRIP S TM                SEQ P    NEW_SEQ
------ - ---------- ---------- - ----------
     1 A 1:10                1            1
     1 B 1:16                2 A          2
     1 B 1:20                2 B          2
     1 B 1:25                2 B          2
     1 C 1:31                3 B          3
     1 B 1:40                4 C          4
     2 A 2:10                1 B          1
     2 B 2:17                2 A          2
     2 C 2:20                3 B          3
     2 B 2:25                4 C          4

 10 rows selected
```

You want to see if the stop changes between one row and the next. If it does, you want to increment the sequence. So use lag to get the previous stop into the current row.

I used DECODE because of the way it handles NULLs and it is more concise than CASE, but if you are following the text book, you should probably use CASE.

Using SUM as an analytic function with an ORDER BY clause will give the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *, dense_rank() over(partition by trip, stop order by time) as sqnc
from yourtable;
```

Use `dense_rank` so you get all the numbers consecutively, with no skipped numbers in between.

Comment: . . This does not do what the OP wants.  It would label the rows 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, . . .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more complicated than a simple `row_number()`.  You need to identify groups of adjacent stops and *then* enumerate them.

You can identify the groups using a difference of row numbers.  Then, a `dense_rank()` on the difference does what you want if there are no repeated stops on a trip:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by trip order by grp, stop)
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by trip order by time) -
              row_number() over (partition by trip, stop order by time)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t;
```

If there are:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (partition by trip order by mintime)
from (select t.*,
             min(time) over (partition by trip, grp, stop) as mintime
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (partition by trip order by time) -
                    row_number() over (partition by trip, stop order by time)
                   ) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: giving wrong result for Trip =2, stop = B, time = 2.25.